# Convert PDO fetchAll array to javascript array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, jquery-autocomplete

I've searched a bit, and I'm unable to find answer to this.

I'm using jQuery autocomplete for a form, and possible autocomplete values come from database.

I've this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [kurssi] => Course 1
            [0] => Course 1
            [tuotekoodi] => Course1Code
            [1] => Course1Code
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [kurssi] => Course2
            [0] => Course2
            [tuotekoodi] => Course2Code
            [1] => Course2Code
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [kurssi] => Course3
            [0] => Course3
            [tuotekoodi] => Course3Code
            [1] => Course3Code
        )

)
```

and I need to have it like this (or in a form that jQuery Autocomplete accepts it):

```
var course = [
"Course1",
"Course2",
"Course3",
];

var code = [
"Course1Code",
"Course2Code",
"Course3Code"];
```

So I have to make two different javascript arrays from a php array, but how?

Comment: You can either SERIALIZE or JSON_ENCODE the array - does this help?

Comment: @RobW PHP Serialize produced this, and I don't know what to do with it: a:3:{i:0;a:4:{s:6:"kurssi";s:8:"Course 1";i:0;s:8:"Course 1";s:10:"tuotekoodi";s:11:"Course1Code";i:1;s:11:"Course1Code";}i:1;a:4:{s:6:"kurssi";s:7:"Course2";i:0;s:7:"Course2";s:10:"tuotekoodi";s:11:"Course2Code";i:1;s:11:"Course2Code";}i:2;a:4:{s:6:"kurssi";s:7:"Course3";i:0;s:7:"Course3";s:10:"tuotekoodi";s:11:"Course3Code";i:1;s:11:"Course3Code";}}

Comment: Try serializeArray instead of just serialize :) http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: @Nilzone I'm not sure am I supposed to use PHP serialize, or jQuery serialize here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to do : 
1: your original array :

```
 $arr = [
     0=>["kursi"=>"Course1","tuotekodi"=>"Course1Code"],
     1=>["kursi"=>"Course2","tuotekodi"=>"Course2Code"],
     2=>["kursi"=>"Course3","tuotekodi"=>"Course3Code"]
     ];
```

2: transform your array to be used for encoding as you want :

```
$toJson =array();
         foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
             foreach($value as $k =>$v){
                 if(isset($toJson[$k])){
                     $toJson[$k][] = $v;
                 }else{
                     $toJson[$k] = array();
                     array_push($toJson[$k], $v);
                 }
             }
}
```

3 : the result :

```
var_dump(json_encode($toJson));
```

[image: pdo-to-json]

Comment: Instead of `var_dump(json_encode($toJson));` I used just `echo json_encode($toJson);` now I can use it! Thanks!

Comment: Oh yeh, sorry that was just an example code, to show the result on page :). I've used stripped down version of my own code that i used to fetch data from 5 tables with lot's of duplicate rows because of the foreign keys,etc… Anyways, glad i could help !

Answer (score 0):

You have to use json_encode() to transport a PHP Array to Javascript. JQuery has own JSON functions, to decode the JSON string to a Javascript object.

Comment: Yes, I tried json_encode($db->fetchAll()); but it only echoed `[]`, so I must've done something wrong?

Comment: @RobW you mean PDO::FETCH_ASSOC?

Comment: @RobW in that case, it produces `{"kurssi":"Course 1","tuotekoodi":"Course1Code"}` and not the full result.

Answer (score 0):

Either serialize or json_encode the string. jQuery provides JSON-decoding methods (getJSON, parseJSON). Example outputs: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/bpr-ndx

Comment: Ah yes, but this puts [kurssi] & [tuotekoodi] in the same array, how would I separate them?